# Is it possible to rotate Pie Chart of Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pie-chart

Is it possible to rotate Pie Chart of Primefaces?

Normal Pie chart generated with primefaces looks like this:

[Original Pie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3NjM4d2tuNFp2Q2s/edit?usp=sharing)

What if I want rotate the pie chart and make the start angle start from top of the pie like this?

[Intended Pie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3YlVOM2NYSEhET2s/edit?usp=sharing)

Sorry for the link because I'm not able to insert image...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Add the attribute `extender="ext1"` to your `<p:pieChart/>` and add the following in your script file:

```
function ext1() {
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
        renderer : $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            // rotate the starting position of the pie around to 12 o'clock.
            startAngle : -90
        }
    };
};
```

Primefaces Charts are generated with jqPlot. For more about it's functions and customization, check the website `http://www.jqplot.com/index.php`

Comment: Can you tell me what is cfg? 

I looked the jqplot website and still don't know what "cfg" stands for.

Comment: Cfg stands for configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination